# How to specify registry credentials on kubectl set image?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a deployment that uses a private registry by the use of `imagePullSecrets`. It is running ok but when I try to update its image by specifying another tag like this:

`kubectl set image deployment/mydeployment mycontainer=my_docker_hub_user/my_image:some_tag`

my pod get a `ImagePullBackOff` status with the message:

`Failed to pull image "my_docker_hub_user/my_image:some_tag": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/my_docker_hub_user/my_image/manifests/some_tag: unauthorized: incorrect username or password`

But I cannot find how to inform user and password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubernetes uses secrets to store the credentials to pull from a private docker registry. You can check out [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) to set it up properly as most likely the `Secret` defined in the `imagePullSecrets` does not have access to your new image. You need to define a `Secret` that has access to the private docker registry and update the deployment with the new `imagePullSecrets`.

Comment: Yes. The problem was that I changed docker hub credentials and forgot to update the secret. The already downloaded image worked but new ones didn't.

Comment: note : if you have a $ in your password, you must escape it by using \$ when declaring the secret like `kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>`